# putting php link variables in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have a javascript which highlights the table row when a user hovers down it. it now also links to a page when you click it. but i want to add php to my link. Can it be done?

I have attempted it myself but it gives me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING

```
<script>
     $(function() {
        $('tr').hover(function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#eee');
            $(this).contents('td').css({'border': '0px solid red', 'border-left': 'none', 'border-right': 'none'});
            $(this).contents('td:first').css('border-left', '0px solid red');
            $(this).contents('td:last').css('border-right', '0px solid red');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
            $(this).contents('td').css('border', 'none');
            $('tr').click(function() { 
    document.location = <?php \"read_message.php?msg={$inbox[0]}\">{$inbox['subject']}"; ?>';
} );
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: before `<?php` add a `'` you aren't opening it. but you are also closing something else after `['subject']}"` with a `"`

Comment: yea tried that still getting same error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.location = '<?php echo \"read_message.php?msg={$inbox[0]}\">{$inbox['subject']}"; ?>';`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
document.location = <?php echo '"read_message.php?msg='.$inbox[0].'">'.$inbox['subject']  ; ?>
```

or

```
 document.location = "read_message.php?msg=<?php echo $inbox[0]; ?>"><?php echo $inbox['subject'].'"'; ?>';
```

Comment: there's still an unmatched `'` at the end

Answer (score 1):

You are getting parser error because `$inbox['subject']` may contain some apostrophe's that are breaking the string opening and closing apostrophes.

Try using the below:

```
document.location = "<?php echo "read_message.php?msg={$inbox[0]}>{$inbox['subject']}" ?>";
```

Comment: That's true, try to keep in mind "clean inputs, filter outputs" (or clean inputs, escape outputs if you prefer)